Is there a notion of an "improper sum", and how does one describe it?
In this recent MSE question, the improper integral
$$I := \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\sin(\color{black}{\pi}\color{black}{x})\zeta(\color{black}{x})\zeta(1-\color{black}{x})
d\color{black}{x} $$ is considered. The integral is improper in two ways. First, it is unbounded on the set over which the integral is taken. Second, it is unbounded vertically, because there are singularities at $x=0$ and $x=1$.
I considered looking at the sum analogue of this integral:
$$S := \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}
\sin(\color{black}{\pi}\color{black}{n})\zeta(\color{black}{n})\zeta(1-\color{black}{n}).
$$
Again we do have singularities at $n=0$ and $n=1$. However, the sum can be evaluated if one takes the limits at $x=0$ and $x=1$ for these summands:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \sin(\color{black}{\pi}\color{black}{x})\zeta(\color{black}{x})\zeta(1-\color{black}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2} = \lim_{x \to 1} \sin(\color{black}{\pi}\color{black}{x})\zeta(\color{black}{x})\zeta(1-\color{black}{x}) .$$
Questions:

How does one formally describe the 'improper sum' in general, and how does one describe it in this case? (I.e. how would one write down a derivation of $S$ in this case?)
Why is there a notion of an 'improper integral', but there appears to be no equivalent notion in the case of sums? I've never encountered the term 'improper sum' before.


A sum is discrete, but an integral is not. So if the function being summed is undefined at a single point, it doesn't exist. But if a function being integrated is undefined at a single point, it can still be defined.

Expanding on Lucenaposition's comment:
Summation is defined on sequences, not functions on open subsets of $\Bbb R$. You can define the sequence from such functions, but that is not part of "summing", which only involves the sequence itself. There are uncountably many functions that would provide the same sequence - even if you only allowed "nice" functions (smooth, or even analytic). So there is no backing out from the sequence to the function it came from.
Thus, from the point of view of summation, there are no such things as "singularities" with values obtained by limits. The indices of the sequence are discrete. They always keep a respectful distance of at least $1$ between themselves. There is no limiting process within a sequence that would fill in a "singularity".
So while there are infinite summations, calling them "improper" is just adding a redundant term for "infinite". And there are no singularities in the middle, as that is just a matter of how you chose the sequence to be summed, not an issue for the summation itself.

I agree.  Note that there are two types of "improper" integrals: (1) those with infinite bounds, and (2) those with discontinuous integrands.  For the summation equivalent, the first type can just be called "infinite sums", and the second type just doesn't exist.
